# Better way to test several functions for the same thing in python

Tags: python, doctest, repeat

Assuming a python file with a whole bunch of functions I want to write tests for the functions using `doctest`. For example every function takes a string and a connection object (`httplib.HTTPConnection(...)`). So I want to test every function if the string is empty or `None`. The tests would look like this.

```
def function_1(mystring, conn):
    r'''
    >>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(...)
    >>> function_1(None, conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NoneAsInputError: `mystring` should be a string and not `None`!

    >>> function_1("", conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    EmptyStringError: `mystring` should not be an empty string!
    '''

    pass

def function_2(mystring, conn):
    r'''
    >>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(...)
    >>> function_2(None, conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NoneAsInputError: `mystring` should be a string and not `None`!

    >>> function_2("", conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    EmptyStringError: `mystring` should not be an empty string!
    '''

    pass

[...]

def function_n(mystring, conn):
    r'''
    >>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(...)
    >>> function_n(None, conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NoneAsInputError: `mystring` should be a string and not `None`!

    >>> function_n("", conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    EmptyStringError: `mystring` should not be an empty string!
    '''

    pass
```

As you can see, the test are identical, only the function name changes. Is it possible to refactor that to avoid code repetition?

Or is there a better way to lump together such tests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never used doctest.

```
def genDocText(func_name):
    return r'''
    >>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(...)
    >>> %(func_name)s(None, conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NoneAsInputError: `mystring` should be a string and not `None`!

    >>> %(func_name)s("", conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    EmptyStringError: `mystring` should not be an empty string!
    ''' % {'func_name': func_name}

def function_1(mystring, conn):
    pass

function_1.__doc__ = genDocText('function_1')
```

Is this a bad way?

**UPDATE**:
Using [decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax) the solution above can be written as:

```
def genDocText(func):
    func.__doc__ = r'''
    >>> conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(...)
    >>> %(func_name)s(None, conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    NoneAsInputError: `mystring` should be a string and not `None`!

    >>> %(func_name)s("", conn)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    EmptyStringError: `mystring` should not be an empty string!
    ''' % {'func_name': func.__name__}
    return func

@genDocText
def function_1(mystring, conn):
    pass

@genDocText
def function_2(mystring, conn):
    pass

@genDocText
def function_n(mystring, conn):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print function_1.__doc__
    print function_2.__doc__
    print function_n.__doc__
```

Comment: This is *indeed* more elegant! I recently read up about decorators, so I luckily can understand your answer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer, but I think it's an important point to make: Please consider using `unittest` for any serious testing of your code. `doctest` is nice but it's limited - I wouldn't use it for anything beyond making sure simple snippets of code in the documentation really work (note - testing the snippets, *not* the module).

With `unittest` you're quite limitless in the amount of customization you can add to your tests and it will allow you to test your code much more thoroughly.